# pygame bullet spawner

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently making a game for myself and i have a lot of code in a function which does almost the exact same thing with some minor differences. I was wondering if there is an way to optimize this
code and still get the same output.

```
import pygame, os, random

def draw_game():
    player = pygame.Rect(450, 350, HOOFD_HEIGHT, HOOFD_WIDTH)

    BULLETS_L = [] 
    BULLETS_R = [] 
    BULLETS_UP = [] 

    HITPOINTS = 4 
    
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)# a random number between 1000 and 6000
    E1 = pygame.USEREVENT + 3 #an custom event 
    pygame.time.set_timer(E1, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))# this activates the event after 1 to 6 seconds
    
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E2 = pygame.USEREVENT + 4
    pygame.time.set_timer(E2, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E3 = pygame.USEREVENT + 5
    pygame.time.set_timer(E3, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E4 = pygame.USEREVENT + 6
    pygame.time.set_timer(E4, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E5 = pygame.USEREVENT + 7
    pygame.time.set_timer(E5, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E6 = pygame.USEREVENT + 8
    pygame.time.set_timer(E6, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E7 = pygame.USEREVENT + 9
    pygame.time.set_timer(E7, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E8 = pygame.USEREVENT + 10
    pygame.time.set_timer(E8, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E9 = pygame.USEREVENT + 11
    pygame.time.set_timer(E9, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E10 = pygame.USEREVENT + 12
    pygame.time.set_timer(E10, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E11 = pygame.USEREVENT + 13
    pygame.time.set_timer(E11, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E12 = pygame.USEREVENT + 14
    pygame.time.set_timer(E12, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E13 = pygame.USEREVENT + 15
    pygame.time.set_timer(E13, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True

    while run == True:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == E1: 
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E1, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(0, 280, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT)
                BULLETS_L.append(bullet)

            if event.type == E2:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E2, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(0, 70, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT)
                BULLETS_L.append(bullet)
                        
            if event.type == E3:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E3, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(0, 620, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT)
                BULLETS_L.append(bullet)

            if event.type == E4:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E4, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(0, 430, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT)
                BULLETS_L.append(bullet)

            if event.type == E5:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E5, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 350, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT)
                BULLETS_R.append(bullet)
                    
            if event.type == E6:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E6, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 175, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT)
                BULLETS_R.append(bullet)

            if event.type == E7:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E7, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 525, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT)
                BULLETS_R.append(bullet)

            if event.type == E8:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E8, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(350, HEIGHT, BULLET_HEIGHT, BULLET_WIDTH)
                BULLETS_UP.append(bullet)

            if event.type == E9:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E9, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(550, HEIGHT, BULLET_HEIGHT, BULLET_WIDTH)
                BULLETS_UP.append(bullet)

            if event.type == E10:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E10, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(750, HEIGHT, BULLET_HEIGHT, BULLET_WIDTH)
                BULLETS_UP.append(bullet)
                
            if event.type == E11:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E11, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(50, HEIGHT, BULLET_HEIGHT, BULLET_WIDTH)
                BULLETS_UP.append(bullet)
                    
            if event.type == E12:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E12, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(235, HEIGHT, BULLET_HEIGHT, BULLET_WIDTH)
                BULLETS_UP.append(bullet)
                
            if event.type == E13:
                B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
                pygame.time.set_timer(E13, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
                bullet = pygame.Rect(1050, HEIGHT, BULLET_HEIGHT, BULLET_WIDTH)
                BULLETS_UP.append(bullet)
                
            if event.type == PLAYER_HIT:
                HITPOINTS -= 1
                BULLET_HIT_SOUND.play()
        
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        movement(keys_pressed, player)

        handle_bullets_R(BULLETS_R, player)
        handle_bullets_L(BULLETS_L, player)
        handle_bullets_up(BULLETS_UP, player)
        draw_window(player, BULLETS_L, HITPOINTS, BULLETS_R, BULLETS_UP)

        DEAD_TXT = ""

        if HITPOINTS <= 0:
            DEAD_TXT = "GAME OVER"
        

        if DEAD_TXT != "":
            end_text(DEAD_TXT)
            run = False
    
    if run == False:
        draw_menu()
```

as seen above, there is alot of code pieces which could probably be optimized way better.

thanks in advance

Comment: The title should be the purpose of the app, not the area you want reviewed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a lot of code ... which does almost the exact same thing

I am glad that you recognize this and wish to learn how to
[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
it up.

There is a separate structural difficulty in this code
that we should address.
The function `draw_game` is entirely too long,
and should be broken up via Extract Helper.
We strive to write functions that can be visually
taken in all at once, with no scrolling,
as an aid to human comprehension.
Usually that means if we've gone on for more than
about fifty lines of source, it's time to break
it into smaller chunks that focus on doing just
[one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

---

I'm not sure, but I *think* that possibly you have
a player which is `HOOFD_HEIGHT` tall that might be a horse?
Or some other hoofed animal?
In which case, prefer to spell it out: `HOOFED_HEIGHT`.

Or perhaps keep both dimensions together in a single tuple:

```
HOOFED_SIZE = (123, 456)  # the original posting doesn't specify

player = pygame.Rect(450, 350, *HOOFED_SIZE)
```

That [starred expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12598109)
will supply both numbers to the `.Rect` method.

BTW, kudos on naming these MANIFEST_CONSTANTS according to the
[usual convention](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

---

```
    BULLETS_L = [] 
    BULLETS_R = [] 
    BULLETS_UP = []
```

You mentioned you'd like to coalesce some things.
I haven't even see how these are used yet,
but the naming is suggestive.
We might combine the first two, or perhaps all three,
in a single datastructure that has a *velocity*
associated with it.
For example, "left" velocities might look like `-1`,
and "right" might correspondingly be `1`.

We probably want lowercase names like `bullets_l` here,
as these don't seem to be constants.
Similarly for `hitpoints`.

---

```
    HITPOINTS = 4
```

This is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).
We *could* define `INITIAL_HEALTH` or `INITIAL_HP` somewhere.
But it would probably be more convenient to push the
magic number into the signature, as a value that
typically we just let default:

```
def draw_game(hitpoints=4):
```

One advantage of that practice is it lets
[unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
conveniently alter the value according to their need.

---

```
    B_SPAWN = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    E1 = pygame.USEREVENT + 3 
    pygame.time.set_timer(E1, 1 * int(B_SPAWN))
```

Push this repeated code down into a helper:

```
from enum import Enum

def spawn(event_type: EventType):
    b_spawn = random.uniform(1000, 6000)
    event = pygame.USEREVENT + event_type
    pygame.time.set_timer(event, 1 * int(b_spawn))
    return event
...
def draw_game...
    ...
    e1 = spawn(EventType.BULLET)
    e2 = spawn(EventType.MISSLE)
    ...
class EventType(Enum):
    BULLET = 3
    MISSLE = 4
    ...
```

If "b" denotes "bullet", please spell it out,
or at a minimum offer a `# comment`.
The source code is unclear, so I'm just guessing here.

An [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)
is a classic way to create objects whose value is arbitrary
and they merely need to be distinct from one another.
That is, enums are one way of coping with magic numbers
and giving them meaningful names.

---

```
    run = True
```

This sounds like a verb, to me, and therefore a terrific
name for a `def run():` function.
Variables OTOH often want noun identifiers,
and here an adjective would make sense,
perhaps `running` or `active`.
A common loop idiom is to define `done = False`
and then keep going `while not done:`

---

```
        for event in pygame.event.get():
```

Break out a helper:

```
def dispatch(event):
    ...
```

Then the `for` loop mostly becomes a single helper call
and we can bury the complexity one level down.

```
            if event.type == E1:
```

There's a lot of copy-n-paste going on here.
Rule of thumb: if you notice you keep leaning on the CMD-V paste key,
it's time to start think about parameters instead.

Using a bunch of `if`s is not *terrible*, exactly;
feel free to keep that structure during initial
[refactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).
But a `dict` that maps from event type to
its relevant parameters can be an excellent
way to implement such dispatch.
You can even put function objects into the map.

---

```
        DEAD_TXT = ""

        if HITPOINTS <= 0:
            DEAD_TXT = "GAME OVER"
        

        if DEAD_TXT != "":
            end_text(DEAD_TXT)
            run = False
    
    if run == False:
        draw_menu()
```

Prefer to deal with it all at once in a single `if` clause:

```
        if HITPOINTS <= 0:
            end_text("GAME OVER")
            run = False    

    draw_menu()
```

Notice that the menu draw happens unconditionally when
we fall off the bottom of the loop.
You had a check which was redundant with the check
at top of loop.
Making the whole `while` loop fit in a single screenful
would have made that more obvious.

---

Overall?

Naming could be improved; that will come with practice.

Break up giant functions that don't fit within a screenful,
using Extract Helper.